# Resolve data for common controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just wanted to know if there is any way to resolve data for a controller not assigned with any route (BaseController common for all actions)

```
App.controller('BaseCtrl',function($http, Service){
    $scope.data = null;
    Service.getData(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Can I can resolve `Service.getData();` before the base controller is loaded and inject the same into it like

```
var Base = App.controller('BasCtrl', function($http, BaseData){
   $scope.data = BaseData; 
});
Base.resolve = {
    BaseData:function(Service){
        return Service.getData();
    }
}
```

Please help if it is possible.

PS: I just want to prepare the data from service before the `BaseCtrl` is loaded and inject the same into it.

Answer (score 0):

If your BaseCtrl is loaded with your home page then you have to fetch data before loading the javascript page containing BaseCtrl and put that into window.BaseData, other wise whichever controller is loaded first load data in there.

If basectrol is first page then you can implement it by immediately-invoked function in separate JS page and put that JS before BaseCtrl js file.

e.g. fetchdata.js

```
(function() {
   window.BaseData= function() {...});
})();
```

You can access BaseData from your angular controller through Global parameter injected to your controller.

Now put files this order

```
<script src= "fetchdata.js"></script>
<script src="basecontroller.js"></script>
```

You see you have to break the rule to do that, but anyway Angular $resource in your Service is also nothing but Ajax implementation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have implemented the same using `App.run()` and it working fine